# Create new Widget on Button pressed

Tags: dart, flutter

How can I create new Widgets on button click? For example, I have this code:

```
child: MaterialButton(

    child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 42.0),
            child: Text(
                "LOGIN",
                style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 25.0,
                    fontFamily: "WorkSansBold"),
            ),
    ),
    onPressed: () {
        var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users';
        http.get(url).then((response) {
            print("Response status: ${response.statusCode}");
            print("Response body: ${response.body}");
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => new SecondScreen()),
            );
        });
    },
)
```

Here I would like to make a new screen with data from the JSON. For the sake of simplicity, lets say that I need to create new `Text()` widget for all `name` and numbers from the JSON response. Something like a telephone-book.

What should `SecondScreen` widget contain in this example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a `ListView` that builds a `Text` widget for each value.

```
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget{

    var values;

    SecondScreen(this.values);

    Widget build(buildcontext context){
        return ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: (context, index){
                if(index < values.length)
                {
                    return Card(child: Text(values[index]));
                }
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

something like so

```
class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
   final String body;
   SecondScreen(this.body);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<dynamic> myList = json.decode(body);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Second Screen')),
      body:  Container(
        child: ListView(
          children: myList.map((e)=>Text(e['name'])).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => new SecondScreen(response.body)),
                );
```